# Query very slow with LEFT AND RIGHT JOIN - SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-ce

I need to query the payment records with between date. The payment table has relation with invoice table while the invoice table has relation with customer table. So all the payment records must be shown even the invoice or the customer record already deleted.

To get less than 50 rows with 1 month period, it will take time more than 1 minutes. Any ideas how to reduce the times?

Here my snippet code :

```
SELECT 
    C.name, I.id as id, P.amount, P.date 
FROM 
    tbl_customer C 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_inv I ON C.id = I.id_customer 
RIGHT JOIN 
    tbl_payment P ON I.id = P.id_invoice 
WHERE 
    P.date >= '20131201' AND P.date <= '20140101'
ORDER BY 
    P.date;
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on I.id_Customer and P.Id_Customer ?

Comment: @ErikEJ : No column id_customer in tbl_payment. Only id_invoice for FK with tbl_invoice. For indexes, nope. Need to do?

Comment: Suggest you add indexes to the fks, yes